# EntityFramework Prevent many to many cascade delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a cascade delete on a database and I don't want EF to do cascade delete for this many to many relationship, because it's redundant and slow.

```
    public class ArtikliBojeEC : EntityTypeConfiguration<ArtikliBoje>
{
    public ArtikliBojeEC()
    {
        this.HasMany(e => e.ArtikliVelicine).WithMany(e => e.ArtikliBoje)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("ArtikliBojeVelicine").MapLeftKey("ArtikliBojeId").MapRightKey("ArtikliVelicineId"));
        this.Ignore(e => e.VezaNaVelicinu);
    }
}
```

I also tried putting this OnModelCreating, with no effect, EF still calls delete for every many to many link table:

```
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
{
    relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to try, but my modelBuilder does not have Model property. Maybe I am missing some namespace? I am using EF 6.2.0.

Comment: I think those examples are for the .NET Core. I am using .NET Framework.

Comment: if you don't mind to use Fluent API then you can prevent it by following the introduction of this link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I've managed it by adding class for link (ArtikliBojeVelicine)  table and defining one to many for each of two tables through this linked table, but, new problem arised, now EF wants to update the link table, but I just want it to ignore it. I think I'll have to manualy set entity state detached for each link table before context save.